# "%w" and "%W" difference in lua?

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

%w and %W as in here:  `Str = string.gsub(Str, “%f[%w]cat%f[%W]”`

What's the difference between a small %w and a big %W ?

Here are more examples:  `for _ in string.gmatch(“\n” .. Str .. “\n”, “%Wcat%W”) do` ,

`if Pos1 == 0 or string.find(Str, “^%W”, Pos1) then`

I know %w matches a word character

So i expect %W matches a capital word character?

Answer (score 6):

`%W` is the *complement* of `%w`, meaning it matches all non-alphanumeric characters.

From [§6.4.1 – Patterns](https://lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4.1) (Lua 5.4):

> %w: represents all alphanumeric characters.

> For all classes represented by single letters (%a, %c, etc.), the corresponding uppercase letter represents the complement of the class. For instance, %S represents all non-space characters.